# Derive column from values in another column in the same dataframe

Tags: r

I have a simple dataframe as follows:

```
Name                                          Number
4332.Dys_FSe_20PCent_HGD_fq.gz                 8
4332.Dys_FSe_10PCent_LGD_fq.gz                 2
4332.Dys_FSe_LGD_fq.gz                 1
4332.GoodDy_10PCent_HGD_.fq.gz    1
4332.GoodDy_LessThan10PCent_HGD_.fq.gz     1
4332.GoodDy_10PCent_HGD_.fq.gz                   1
4332.GoodDy_10PCent_HGD_.fq.gz          1
4332.GoodDy_15PCent_HGD_.fq.gz             1
4332.GoodDy_10PCent_HGD_.fq.gz            1
4332.GoodDys_15PCent_HGD_.fq.gz         4
```

I want to extract the substring HGD or LGD and place it in another column called Grade so that the result is:

```
Name                                    Number      Grade
4332.Dys_FSe_20PCent_HGD_fq.gz                 8    HGD
4332.Dys_FSe_10PCent_LGD_fq.gz                 2    LGD
4332.Dys_FSe_LGD_fq.gz                 1            LGD
4332.GoodDy_10PCent_HGD_.fq.gz    1                 HGD
4332.GoodDy_LessThan10PCent_HGD_.fq.gz     1        HGD
4332.GoodDy_10PCent_HGD_.fq.gz                   1  HGD
4332.GoodDy_10PCent_HGD_.fq.gz          1           HGD
4332.GoodDy_15PCent_HGD_.fq.gz             1        HGD
4332.GoodDy_10PCent_HGD_.fq.gz            1         HGD
4332.GoodDys_15PCent_HGD_.fq.gz         4           HGD
```

I guess I'm using grep and paste here but I dont know how to create a column based on the grep and then paste the new column onto the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a couple of ways to extract the substring.  One option is `str_extract` from `library(stringr)`.  We match one or more uppercase LETTERS (`[A-Z]+`) that precedes a `_` (`(?=_)`) and follows another `_` (`(?<=_)`) using the regex lookarounds and extract that matching characters.

```
library(stringr)
df1$Grade <- str_extract(df1$Name, '(?<=_)[A-Z]+(?=_)')
df1$Grade
#[1] "HGD" "LGD" "LGD" "HGD" "HGD" "HGD" "HGD" "HGD" "HGD" "HGD"
```

If we already know that the 'Grade' will be just 3 characters and there are no other 3 letter uppercase LETTERS, the below should also work

```
str_extract(df1$Name, '[A-Z]{3}')
#[1] "HGD" "LGD" "LGD" "HGD" "HGD" "HGD" "HGD" "HGD" "HGD" "HGD"
```

---

Or using `sub`, we match the uppercase letters and capture as a group by placing them in the parentheses (`(A-Z]{3})`) and in the replacement argument use `\1' to get that substring.

```
sub('.*_([A-Z]{3,})_.*$', '\\1', df1$Name)
#[1] "HGD" "LGD" "LGD" "HGD" "HGD" "HGD" "HGD" "HGD" "HGD" "HGD"
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(Name = c("4332.Dys_FSe_20PCent_HGD_fq.gz",
"4332.Dys_FSe_10PCent_LGD_fq.gz", 
"4332.Dys_FSe_LGD_fq.gz", "4332.GoodDy_10PCent_HGD_.fq.gz", 
"4332.GoodDy_LessThan10PCent_HGD_.fq.gz", 
"4332.GoodDy_10PCent_HGD_.fq.gz", "4332.GoodDy_10PCent_HGD_.fq.gz", 
"4332.GoodDy_15PCent_HGD_.fq.gz", "4332.GoodDy_10PCent_HGD_.fq.gz", 
"4332.GoodDys_15PCent_HGD_.fq.gz"), Number = c(8L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L)), .Names = c("Name", "Number"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```